# How do you verify user input in C?

Tags: c, validation

Ok so I want to preface this by saying I know very little about C. I'm studying it independently at my high school and so I've come to you folks for help. I'm taking C1 and I don't know if that's # or ++ or just C or even what the differences are between those. Anyways my question is how do I make sure that a user enters an integer instead of a float, or make sure that the person did not enter a & symbol into the float input.

I code in notepad and save them as .c files and then gcc them in a command prompt if that will give you any idea about what I'm working with.

Comment: wait - how do you write code without knowing which language it's written in?

Comment: @Nim There are lessons that go along with what I'm learning and they just tell me what I have to make and I know a few statements to get all of that done. I know the code I just don't know what it is called. It's not very hard to program in a language without knowing what the hell you're doing :) Think about all of the little kids that know how to program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the functions declared in the header file [`ctype.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_character_classification), in particular the function [`isdigit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isdigit.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose you are programming C, by your comment about gcc. But going into the question, if you are using `scanf`, then it pretty much checks everything, you just have to know how to use it, for example:

```
int main(void)
{
    float input;
    if(scanf("%f", &input) == 1)
    {
        printf("OK, I could read your float: %f.\n", input);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not OK, I couldn't read your float.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I input `5.4654`, it will print the correct number.
If I input `5.4&654` it will print `5.4`, because there was a float in there, and it went until the `&` character.
But if I input `abc`, it will fail, and print it could not read your float.

The reason this works is because `scanf` returns the number of successful data read. So if you ask for `"%f %f %d"`, you have to check if the return value is `3`, if so, everything went OK, despite random characters that would be in the way but not being read.

Or alternatively, talking about integer types (and similar), you could use the [functions provided by `ctype.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/ctype.h.html).

Comment: I'd suggest `fgets` instead of `scanf`. Do something like this `char buff[20]; fgets(buff, size, stdin);`. It seems that `scanf` could break your propram with a buffer overflow. I think that you're safer with `fgets` since you can size up your input.

Comment: For catching strings, pretty much yes.

Answer (score 0):

Bestest way is to read lines of input with [fgets()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) and parse the lines. For numeric input, [strtol()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) for integers and/or [strtod()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) for floating-point numbers are the most comprehensive function to use.

eg

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[100];
    char *err;
    int intval;

    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

    errno = 0;
    intval = strtol(line, &err, 10);
    /* check for errors */
    if (errno) /* error */;
    if (*err != '\n') /* error */;

    return 0;
}
```